# Webpart broken after solution redeploy

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have deployed and then redeployed a .wsp on a Sharepoint 2010 server (the solution was developed on another 2010 server). The solution contains 2 web parts.

After retracting and removing the old solution, I added and deployed the same solution again, with no errors.

Afterwards, I deactivated and reactivated the feature installed through my .wsp file.

The problem is that whenever I try to add one of those 2 web parts to a page, I get an error saying "The operation could not be completed because the item was removed from the gallery".

Do you have any ideea what's happening? Anu help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Usually this happens if the web part gets orphaned in the web part gallery.  Try Deactivating your solution and Retract and Uninstall your wsp.  Then check the Web Part Gallery for the site collection.  If you still see your web parts there then manually delete them.

Then you can Add and Deploy your wsp and activate your solution.  The web parts should then be available in the web part gallery and be able to be added to your pages.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a more simple solution which worked well for me.

Go to the webparts gallery at *Site Settings/Galleries/Web parts* and delete problematic webpart entry. Then deactivate and reactivate the wsp which contains that webpart and everything should work fine. No need for redeployment or uninstalling.

[Source](https://kmukesh.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-because-item-was-removed-from-the-gallery/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but in my case after a thorough search in web part gallery found out that some web parts having the same name, but without assembly's prefix have created.

The solution is just to sort the web parts with the date and you'll get the new web parts.

Some times it happens that every thing is same as before, but SharePoint forgets the settings which are placed in webpart.xml file